# Getting new lines from database to html textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have this code

```
<script>
  var database="<%=rsta2.getString("data").replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]","<br />")%>";
  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
  newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<textarea rows="15" cols="70" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox" >' + database + '</textarea>')
  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
  counter++;
</script>

  <body>
  <div id=TextBoxesGroup>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Initially I add data like this

[image]

Using the above code gives me

[image]

What am I doing wrong?I tried to replace `<br />` with `&#xA` ,I get new line but an extra line feed along with it.What should I do so that next line appears?Instead of 
 i want the hello2 to come on next line.

Another query is suppose I have quotes("this is my dog") to retrieve, how should I write it?How should I retrieve the quotes("") cause it throws an error.(UNexpected identifier)
For example `<%=rsta2.getString("data").replaceAll("["]","&quot")%>`,
I know the above doesnt work,but How should I write it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this ,

```
html('<textarea rows="15" cols="70" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox" >' + database + '</textarea>
```

Have you closed this statement properly ?

Also please more clear in the second part , cant get what you saying?

*Another query is suppose I have quotes to retrieve, how should I write it? For example `<%=rsta2.getString("data").replaceAll("["]","&quot")%>` I know the above doesnt work,but How should I write it?*

Comment: sorry to say,but i cant find ny difference between ur suggested code with my code

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the data within the quotes or the entire string ?

Comment: It was there in my code too,forgot to put it..sorry about that

Comment: I want the quotes also to appear,it throws an error when i check it google developing tool`unexpected identifier`.But help me solve the first problem if u could

Comment: Whats your JSP configuration ? Is that `character encoding is UTF-8.`

Comment: yup utf-8...does that create problem?

Comment: Yes it needs to UTF-8

Comment: So then what must be creating the problem?ny other suggestions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45262/discussion-between-san-krish-and-user3040563)